# Getting SSL certificate chain from jabber server

Tags: ssl, xmpp

trying to connect my jabber client (pidgin) to a jabber server with self signed certificate, I am getting an "unable to validate certificate" error.

As it is not possible to tell the client not to validate the chain, I would like to get the certificate chain in order to import it there. Therefore I use:

```
openssl s_client -connect my.jabber.server.net:5222 </dev/null
```

I am getting the following answer:

openssl s_client -connect cup1.sprachdienst.fraunhofer.de:5222

```
> CONNECTED(00000003) 140472458057376:error:140790E5:SSL
> routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
> --- no peer certificate available
> --- No client certificate CA names sent
> --- SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 213 bytes
> --- New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE) Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported Compression: NONE Expansion: NONE
> ---
```

Why don't I get the certificate chain while my jabber client does?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is: Jabber requires starttls:

```
openssl s_client -connect my.jabber.server.net:5222 </dev/null -starttls xmpp
```

returns the certificate

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a previous answer, Jabber/XMPP requires [`-starttls`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/s_client.html).

**Client-to-server (c2s) certificate** for `my.jabber.server.net`.

```
openssl s_client -connect my.jabber.server.net:5222 </dev/null -starttls xmpp
```

To expand upon that answer, there are two types of connections:

- Normal client logins: `-starttls xmpp`, default port 5222
- Connection between servers: `-starttls xmpp-server`, default port 5269

**Server-to-server (s2s) certificate** for `my.jabber.server.net`.

```
openssl s_client -connect my.jabber.server.net:5269 </dev/null -starttls xmpp-server
```

---

With `openssl` v1.1.0+ you can also check custom domains, with the [`-xmpphost <domain>`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/s_client.html) flag, or use the [option alias `-name`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/8176431d5901ed09c8cd99c85178f43172741ddc) in `openssl` v1.1.1+.

**Client-to-server (c2s) certificate for custom domain** `other.example.org` hosted by `my.jabber.server.net`:

```
openssl s_client -connect my.jabber.server.net:5222 </dev/null -starttls xmpp -xmpphost other.example.org
```

**Server-to-server (s2s) certificate for custom domain** `other.example.org` hosted by `my.jabber.server.net`:

```
openssl s_client -connect my.jabber.server.net:5269 </dev/null -starttls xmpp-server -xmpphost other.example.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy Way,

1. Close Pidgin
2. Find your certificates folder (`Win­dows: %appdata%\.purple`) 
   (Linux: `/home/<Username>/.purple/certificates/x509/tls_peers`)
3. Delete everything in the certificate folder.
4. Restart pid­gin and eventually you should get a new certificate that works.

P.S: Windows users who aren’t familiar with `%app­data%` just type `%appdata%\.purple` in your address bar and press enter.

Comment: Not if your server is presenting a self-signed cert (although it's not good to blindly accept a cert downloaded in this fashion). If this is happening to you, you'll see:
`nss:   ERROR -8172: SEC_ERROR_UNTRUSTED_ISSUER`
in the debug window for one of the received certs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this answer, if you want to specifically grab the cup-xmpp certificate using RSA and not ECDSA, you'll want to use

openssl s_client -connect my.jabber.server.net:5222 -starttls xmpp -cipher aRSA -tls1_2

Jabber will use the RSA cert in almost all cases, as it has higher preference by default.

Answer (score -1):

Generating the self-signed cert with the following command worked for me:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -keyout example.key -out example.crt -subj /CN=example.com -addext subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:example.net,IP:10.0.0.1
```

(Command found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl))

Comment: Hi, the question is about how to get already generated and installed certificate from the jabber server, not generating new one.